# With Rust Regular Expressions, how can I use named capture groups preceding a string?

Tags: regex, rust

I'm using the [`sd` tool](https://github.com/chmln/sd) which uses rust regular expressions, and I am trying to use it with a named capture group, however if in the replacement the named capture group precedes a string, then the string is included as the potential the for named capture group, causing unexpected behaviour.

Here is a contrived example to illustrate the issue:

```sh
echo 'abc' | sd -p '(?P<cg>b)' '$cgB'
# outputs: ac
# desired output: abBc

echo 'abc' | sd -p '(?P<cg>b)' '$cg B'
# outputs as expected: ab Bc
# however, places a space there
```

I've tried `$<cg>B`, `$cg(B)`, `$cg\0B`, all don't give `abBc`.

I've also checked the [rust regex docs](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/) however the x flag, and other techniques seem only applicable to the search pattern, not the replace pattern.

Comment: Why make the question about the sd tool when it's easy to reproduce with just Rust and the regex crate ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret I'm not actually a rust programmer, just a sd and ripgrep user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't need the `sd` tool to reproduce this behavior. Here it is in pure Rust:

```rust
let re = regex::Regex::new(r"(?P<n>b)").unwrap();
let before = "abc";
assert_eq!(re.replace_all(before, "$nB"), "ac");
assert_eq!(re.replace_all(before, "${n}B"), "abBc");
```

The brace replacement syntax isn't described in the front documentation but on the [documentation of the `replace` method](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.replace):

> The longest possible name is used. e.g., $1a looks up the capture
> group named 1a and not the capture group at index 1. To exert more
> precise control over the name, use braces, e.g., ${1}a.

In short, unless there's a character that can't be part of a name just after in the replacement pattern, you should always put the group name between braces.

Answer (score -1):

For the rust regexes via sd via bash use case in the question:

```sh
echo 'abc' | sd -p '(?P<cg>b)' '${cg}B'
```